# Multiselect dropdown/list in django admin panel only

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

[django model choice option as a multi select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582544/django-model-choice-option-as-a-multi-select-box)

[Django Multiple Choice Field / Checkbox Select Multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726476/django-multiple-choice-field-checkbox-select-multiple)

[Django: How can i create a multiple select form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393134/django-how-can-i-create-a-multiple-select-form)

I'm trying to add a multiselect field in existing django model.
I went through these three SOF threads and some other blogs but I didn't find required solution. everyone is using modelForms.

I want this in purely in default django admin panel (same as choice field).
this field is not going to be used in front-end/any kind of form. purely for admin purpose.

How can I achieve this.

I can create another model for this and then ManytoMany relation but I wonder if there exist
some thing like

`field = models.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[a list of choices])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your models.py

```
from django.db import models
from model_utils import Choices
awesome_choices=('Choice 1', 'Choice 2',)
class SomeAwesomeModel(models.Model):
    myfield=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field_not_in_front_end=models.Charfield(max_length=255, choices=Choices(*awesome_choices))
```

in your forms.py

```
from .models import SomeAwesomeModel
from django import forms

class SomeAwesomeModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=SomeAawesomeModel
        fields=['myfield']
```

This won't put your field in front-end but will show in admin as a drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to select multiple values at the same time, use this project's MultiSelectField:

https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield

MultiSelectField renders a group of independently-selectable checkboxes in the Django admin page.