# Django model multiple select field but not multi select box

Tags: django, multiple-choice, multichoiceitems, multiplechoicefield

How to let user be multiple-choice in Django models? Do I need django-multiselectfield, but it's choices are user-defined, right?([sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582544/django-model-choice-option-as-a-multi-select-box)), not the data from user models.  I want to make multiple-choice users, not single choice,  I pasted my code as below, Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ManyToManyField ` class id by default using multiple select form. could you post your form model and the view?

Comment: Thank you for reading my code, I already add forms.py and views.py, now I received a error of "django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'skill'. Choices are: department, teacher
", I don't know where the problem is..........

Comment: This is what you need to do in your ModelForm
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: It strange, you already use `CheckboxSelectMultiple ` widget but in the HTML it shows select box, could you post your template file?